# «По какой-то странной причине» — обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли обособлять этот оборот?

*Я пригласил Барса-кота, но(,) **по какой-то странной причине**(,) он не пришёл вообще-вообще.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Доброго всем дня!**

Вот заглянула на форум и заинтересовалась этой темой. Многое показалось мне странным (в самом вопросе, и в ответе, и в отсутствии его обсуждения), многое  **не сходилось и не клеилось**. Или это я ошибаюсь, а там все идеально? И я решила поделиться своими сомнениями с вами.

*Я пригласил Барса-кота, но(,) по **какой-то странной причине**(,) он не пришёл вообще.*

**1.  Семантика**

Сама ситуация необычной и странной не выглядит. Что странного в том, что вы пригласили кого-то, а он не пришел? В конце концов, просто не смог прийти, а указать причину не было возможности.

**2. Лексика**

Предложение можно записать так: *Я пригласил Барса-кота, но он **почему-то** не пришёл.*

Можно ли вместо «почему-то»  использовать сочетание **«по какой-то причине»**? Можно (семантика та же), но не очень логично. Даже при отсутствии обособления такой оборот кажется подчеркнутым, а зачем это делать? Да и стиль у него книжный.

Сочетание **«по какой-то странной причине**» нелогично тем более. Этот оборот предполагает какое-то непонятное **действие** субъекта (как в приведенных в ответе примерах), а в нашем случае действия вообще нет.

**О слове «вообще».**  Его значение желательно посмотреть в словаре. Слово многозначное, но в конечном итоге просматривается  семантика прилагательного «общий»  (общее, целое, основное). Ситуация должна  обозначаться  как сравнение чего-то общего и его частных вариантов.

Тогда это должно выглядеть так: *Я пригласил Барса-кота, он собирался прийти, потом сказал, что немного опоздает, но в конце концов не пришёл **вообще**.* Но в заданном предложении этого тоже нет.

**3. Авторская структура предложения и обособление оборота**

Обычно мы доверяем автору, так как он подбирает структуру по семантике всего текста. Можно ли  считать это предложение некорректным? Такая структура вполне приемлема, а обособление в общем случае  допускается, если есть желание подчеркнуть значимость оборота.

Но здесь дело в том, что **сам оборот** не выглядит обоснованным, надо сначала разобраться с этой проблемой.

**4. Вывод**

Да, вопросов больше, чем ответов…  Возможно, вы не согласитесь со мной, но тема уже закрыта, всеми одобрена и ни у кого не вызвала  сомнений. (Удивительно, конечно, но это так.) Поэтому новое обсуждение ни к чему, но можно добавить вот что.

Наш язык требует к себе **много внимания**, и каждое слово в нем значимо. В него надо вслушаться, надо найти ему нужное место. Не стоит высказывать быстрых суждений и сразу же делать однозначные выводы, так как они могут оказаться неверными.

Comment: Шарон, может, вы мне объясните, почему все меня обходят? У меня два вопроса. Сейчас третий будет.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Артем. Я пока не знаю, но обещаю с ними разобраться :)  Как это они вас обходят!   Но чуть позже, по возможности,  договорились? А пока времени не хватает.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Здравствуйте! ;)

Comment: Артем, я видела три ваших вопроса из числа последних. За вопрос, заданный сегодня, вы уже получили два голоса. Давайте посмотрим, будут ли ответы. Если нет, то я отвечу сама. На вопрос про "двое" уже много комментариев, и это тоже мешает участникам давать полноценные ответы.  У меня есть версия, но она довольно простая, а комментарии я просто не понимаю.  Наверное, тоже отвечу. Про квартиру интересный вопрос, но вот ответов тоже нет, а ведь могли бы ответить. И мне было бы интересно послушать. Версия у меня тоже есть.

Comment: Отлично, что у вас версии есть и что готовы ответить! Спасибо вам за эту готовность и за краткий комментарий про все эти вопросы! Да, как раз эти))

Answer (score 4):

[**По какой-то причине**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/121247/%D0%BF%D0%BE), по странной причине, по какой-то странной причине, по неизвестной причине — это наречные выражения, то есть словосочетания, имеющие значение наречия (*неизвестно почему, почему-то, отчего-то*); к вводным не относятся.

При таком построении и смысле предложения (*извернутое* оно у вас, *перенакрученное*) считаю, что **запятые не нужны**.

Написала бы так (без "вообще-вообще", оно тут лишнее):
*Я пригласил кота Барса, но по какой-то странной причине он не пришёл.*

Или так (уже ж с "вообще"):
*Я пригласил кота Барса. Сказал, что опоздает. Но по какой-то странной причине он вообще не пришёл. Вообще.*

> Про них так и говорили: «Мария с Тетериным не придут», «Мария с Тетериным опять поругались», как будто, выйдя за него замуж, она не только не приняла его фамилию, **но по какой-то странной причине** даже лишила его собственного имени (Андрей Геласимов. Дом на Озерной).
>
> огда она носила фамилию Крашенинникова, **но по какой-то причине** ее поменяла, хотя замуж вроде бы не выходила (В. И. Максимов. Дневник научного сотрудника).